# Using Java libraries in Scala

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I am new to Scala. I am only able to write basic code thus far, but I want to start using it more concretely, rather than just learning theory.

Let's say I have the following Java code in *HelloWorld.java*:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }

}
```

What would the code be to invoke it from Scala?

Comment: @Reimeus: No.. I want to call HelloWorld function from scala?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In your example, you just have a main, not a function you would necessarily call from somewhere else. But let's said you did have a function like

```
package com.example.hello;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void sayHello() {
    System.out.println("Hello, world!");
  }
}
```

(I also added a package for your example, for completeness). Then in your Scala code, you could do:

```
import com.example.hello._

object GreetWorld extends App {
  (0 until 10).foreach {
    HelloWorld.sayHello()
  }
}
```

to say hello using the Java function 10 times in Scala. The `._` in the `import` imports all members of the package, or alternatively you could just `import com.example.hello.HelloWorld`. You could even import the method itself with `import com.example.hello.HelloWorld.sayHello` so that you don't need to reference the `HelloWorld` object in your code.

Both languages compile into JVM bytecode, so calling Java code from Scala is very simple, although calling Scala from Java can be trickier if there are are implicit parameters involved.

Comment: Hi, May I request you to please write the code completely.. I am very new to scala.. 
My scala codeblock is inside the "object" definition.. and rest of the stuff is same.. Does scala and java files should be in same folder??

Comment: I am getting this error : helloworld.scl:1: error: object example is not a member of package com
import com.example.hello

Comment: @Fraz if you still have the problem, see changes above

Comment: `(0 to 10)` is 11 times, not 10. the range is inclusive.

Comment: Maybe the code was updated, but it says 0 until 10, not 0 to 10, and until is not inclusive.

Comment: @samboosalis was in a hurry it seems. Didn't read it right. No, the code hasn't been modified since the answer was posted.

Comment: @frazman you need compile java files first. i.e. `javac ./com/example/hello/HelloWorld.java`.

Comment: Does anyone knows if this sample works in  Databricks Notebooks?
I mean, having a JAR File attached to a cluster and call java classes inside that JAR from Scala Notebook. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent code would be:

```
object HelloWorld extends App {
  println("Hello, world!")
}
```

If you saved that code in a file called `HelloWorld.scala` then you could compile and run it like so:

```
$ scalac HelloWorld.scala

$ scala HelloWorld
Hello, world!
```

Or if you are working in the REPL:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object HelloWorld extends App {
  println("Hello, world!")
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined module HelloWorld

scala> HelloWorld.main(Array.empty[String])
Hello, world!
```

Answer (score 2):

```
object HelloWorld{
      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      println("hello world")
    }

}
```

or

```
object HelloWorld extends App {
  println("Hello, world!")
}
```